# Cisco FMC stuck on boot menu screen on eve-ng

Tags: cisco, gns3, lab, cisco-firepower

Any time I restart Cisco FMC on eve-ng, it doesn't boot the default image. When I connect via VNC and press enter or type the image version to boot, it doesn't respond to laptop keystrokes . I was able to get it to boot once after pressing random keys on my laptop keyboard but I can't get it to work any longer.
Kindly assist.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try upgrading to 6.5.0 and seeing if that has the same issue.  It could be a compatibility issue they've addressed.